# ¿Cómo puedo comprobar en un if si una fecha es antes que otra en PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, condiciones, plsql

Llevo unos días intentando hacer un procedimiento que me compare dos fechas, si una es mayor que la otra, hace una cosa y si no lo es, pues hace otra.

Aquí os dejo un ejemplo:

```
create or replace procedure prueba (p_fecha date)
is
    cursor c_fecha
    is
    select fechahora
    from horarios
    where codigocofradia = '0'
    and calle = 'Salida';
    v_fecha c_fecha%rowtype;
begin
    open c_fecha;
    fetch c_fecha into v_fecha;
    if p_fecha < v_fecha then
        dbms_output.put_line(p_fecha||' es menor que '||v_fecha);
        close c_fecha;
    else
        dbms_output.put_line(p_fecha||' es mayor que '||v_fecha);
        close c_fecha;
    end if;
end;
```

El caso es que me sale de error:

```
13/12    PLS-00306: n·mero o tipos de argumentos err¾neos al llamar a '<'
```

Y no se cómo hacer este if sin que me salga este error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que estas comparando contra todo el ROW, no contra el campo en particular,  quizás si probás con;

```
if p_fecha < v_fecha.fechahora then
...
```

Acá podes encontrar un poco mas sobre esto http://www.juntadeandalucia.es/servicios/madeja/contenido/recurso/736

Answer (score 0):

Definir la variable **v_fecha** por el tipo de dato de la columna.
Recuerde que en Oracle las variables y columnas de tipo **DATE** incluyen **siempre** el componente de tiempo horas-minutos-segundos.

```
create or replace procedure prueba(p_fecha date)
is
    cursor c_fecha
    is
    select fechahora
    from horarios
    where codigocofradia = '0'
      and calle = 'Salida';

    v_fecha horarios.fechahora%type;
begin
    open c_fecha;
    --   
    fetch c_fecha 
    into v_fecha;
    --
    if p_fecha < v_fecha then
        dbms_output.put_line(p_fecha||' es menor que '||v_fecha);
    else
        dbms_output.put_line(p_fecha||' es mayor o igual que '||v_fecha);
    end if;
    --
    close c_fecha;
end;
```

Si se desea comparar sin tener en cuenta horas minutos y segundos, entonces es así:

```
create or replace procedure prueba(p_fecha date)
is
    cursor c_fecha
    is
    select fechahora
    from horarios
    where codigocofradia = '0'
      and calle = 'Salida';

    v_fecha horarios.fechahora%type;
begin
    open c_fecha;
    --   
    fetch c_fecha 
    into v_fecha;
    --
    if trunc(p_fecha)<trunc(v_fecha) then
        dbms_output.put_line(p_fecha||' es menor que '||v_fecha);
    else
        dbms_output.put_line(p_fecha||' es mayor o igual que '||v_fecha);
    end if;
    --
    close c_fecha;
end;
```